# org.w3c.dom.ls.LSSerialize - setting text wrapping, indentation size

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, xml-serialization, xerces

I am using the following code to indent an xml document which is provided to me as a string.

I am using the JDK implementation of `org.w3c.dom.ls`, if that matters.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/ls/package-summary.html

```
public String format(String xml) {

    try {
        final InputSource src = new InputSource(new StringReader(xml));
        final Node document = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().parse(src).getDocumentElement();
        final Boolean keepDeclaration = Boolean.valueOf(xml.startsWith("<?xml"));

    //May need this: System.setProperty(DOMImplementationRegistry.PROPERTY,"com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.DOMImplementationSourceImpl");

        final DOMImplementationRegistry registry = DOMImplementationRegistry.newInstance();
        final DOMImplementationLS impl = (DOMImplementationLS) registry.getDOMImplementation("LS");
        final LSSerializer writer = impl.createLSSerializer();

        writer.getDomConfig().setParameter("format-pretty-print", Boolean.TRUE); // Set this to true if the output needs to be beautified.
        writer.getDomConfig().setParameter("xml-declaration", keepDeclaration); // Set this to true if the declaration is needed to be outputted.

        return writer.writeToString(document);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Is there a way to define any of the following:

- size of indentation
- whether to do text wrapping or not,
- maximum line length if I want to do text wrapping

I've tried looking at the javadocs, and online examples... but could not find any example. I only saw examples that use an old API, which is now deprecated.